# issue posting pictures

Tags: support

Perhaps this is an exchange-wide issue, but I keep getting "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." when trying to upload a picture to my question. Clicking OK does nothing, and the upload box disappears. Is there a way around this, or is this a bug, or this an issue on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a size limit to uploaded images - 2MB.

Make sure the image is less than this and you shouldn't have a problem.

The issue is complex, and essentially stems from the web server rejecting uploads of a certain size.

Comment: That might be it. The picture in question is 4.7 Mb. I'll redo it and try again. Thanks.